# Magento 2.0 - Difference between migrated product and normal product

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I migrated the products data from Magento 1.9 to 2.0.  Just noticed there is a difference in the way how products are created.  See the images below.

**Edit page of a migrated product**

[image]

**Edit page of a normal product**

[image]

You can see the difference.  For example, the first screen shows 'Migration_General' but the second screen shows 'Product Details'...

I don't find any error. The migrated products are displayed as usual.  But why the admin view showing the difference?

Update :
There are 3 product attribute set found and the migrated products refer to a different attribute set and the new product refer to the default attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it's a bug.

To me it looks like you had the following tabs in your product attribute sets on Magento 1.9:

- General
- Prices
- Meta Information
- etc...

Those tabs are not present on Magento 2 by default. Thus the migration tool added them to your migrated product in order for you to have a similar view of your product after migration.

Your normal product does not have the same structure in its attribute set that's why you don't see the same tabs.

Comment: Thanks.  In my old Magento 1.9 I have only 1 custom product attribute..  In the migrated 2.0 I could see there are 3 attributes set.  The migrated products refer a different attribute set and the new products refer the default attribute set.  How can I change the migrated products attribute to default one?

Comment: I reckon you'll have to manually edit the attribute sets to make them look similar. Open default in one window, and the migrated attribute set in another one, then modify your migrated attribute set to make it look like the default one.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have perform M 1.9 to M 2.3 Migration, I have successfully  Migrate 12k products but all product is assign to one attribute set "Migration_Default", Can you tell me why this is happen? This will affect My products behaviour  or say product custom option?